# Get Watson Conversation Workspaces

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I am using Watson Conversation services on Bluemix. We have multiple Conversation workspaces within the service to enable better segmentation of the problem space.

I need to load information on the set of available workspaces within the Conversation service (e.g. name, workspace ID) to allow me to target the appropriate Conversation API endpoint. I've been trying to find a Watson or Bluemix API to allow me to retrieve the information directly but have not had any success.

Does anyone know if it is possible to retrieve this information programmatically and if there are any best practices for doing so?

Comment: The API reference for the Watson Conversation service is available here ( https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/conversation/api/v1/). However, I think that you are looking for additional information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We don't have an exposed endpoint for this capability at this point. It is something being discussed internally, however.

Comment: Collin, it sounds like you are perhaps on one of the Watson or Bluemix teams? If so, can you please edit your question to state this (and which group you're with)? Authoritative answers from the source are always much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for the information, @Collin. I'll fallback to another method until an appropriate endpoint becomes available.

Comment: This is a greatly needed functionality. Right now, the only alternative seems to be hard-coding the list of available workspace ids on the client side...

Answer (score 3):

The [API for managing Conversation workspaces](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/conversation/api/v1/#workspaces) is now available. It is possible to list workspaces, to create/update/delete a workspace and to download an entire workspace. The API is supported by the [Watson SDKs](http://redirect.viglink.com/?format=go&jsonp=vglnk_149070166380511&key=fc09da8d2ec4b1af80281370066f19b1&libId=j0tdr2xl01012xfw000DA1olwa94fopo5e&loc=http%3A%2F%2Fblog.4loeser.net%2F2017%2F03%2Fmanage-your-watson-conversations-from.html&v=1&out=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ibm.com%2Fwatson%2Fdevelopercloud%2Fdeveloper-tools.html&title=Data%20Henrik%3A%20IT%2C%20Life%2C%20DB2%2C%20and%20more%3A%20Manage%20Your%20Watson%20Conversations%20from%20the%20Command%20Line%20or%20App&txt=Watson%20Developer%20Tools).

Using the new API, I wrote a small [tool for managing Conversation workspaces](http://blog.4loeser.net/2017/03/manage-your-watson-conversations-from.html). The tool shows the API in action. The [source is available on GitHub](https://github.com/data-henrik/watson-conversation-tool) to demonstrate how the API can be of use.